# How can I seperate the flask folders in app.route?

Tags: python, file, flask

Okay, yes the title is confusing. I have no clue how to write this into a title.

I have an app.route in flask for some assets.

```
@app.route('/assets/css/<path:path>')
def send_css(css_file):
  return send_from_directory('assets/css', css_file)
```

What happens In the browser is that "assets/css" becomes one folder called "assets/css" like the image below:

[image]

How do I get the file structure to be like:

```
assets > css > style.css
```

and not:

```
assets/css > style.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
> assets/css
    > style.css
```

is the same thing as this:

```
> assets
    > css
        > style.css
```

The reason it shows up like that is to save space in the browser, because `css` is empty.

If you added another placeholder folder or file into css, you'd see it show up like this:

```
> assets
    > placeholder
    > css
        > style.css
```